# Boostrap Multiselect

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, multi-select, bootstrap-multiselect

How do I change this orange colour?[arrow to the colour, it is orange by default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dw4Xz.png)

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
 $('#laryngology_general').multiselect({
 buttonClass:'btn btn-warning',
 buttonWidth:'260px',
 enableFiltering: true,
 enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
 includeSelectAllOption: false,
 filterPlaceholder:'Search Here..'
 });
```

using:

Answer (score 1):

Lots of ways to do that, but one easy way would be to make your own class and replace `buttonClass:'btn btn-warning'` with `buttonClass:'btn yourclasshere'`

You should also read up on the classes in bootstrap: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/